# Fade a css border to invisible?

Tags: javascript, extjs, css

Is it possible to fade an element's border away? To clarify, this needs to be triggered from javascript, and using something like jquery for animation is NOT an option. We're using sencha but it doesn't look like you can animate anything but element size and position with extjs. I know css3 has some handy animation, but I can't find anything similar to my needs.

Comment: Guess you could always write your own tweening function shrink width to 0 and fade color to transparent, if nothing else.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
div.transition {
  border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ffffff;

  -webkit-transition: border-color 1s linear; /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
     -moz-transition: border-color 1s linear; /* FF3.7+ */
       -o-transition: border-color 1s linear; /* Opera 10.5 */
          transition: border-color 1s linear;
}

div.transition:hover {
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/bcn5c/1/

Comment: for fade out the :hover state `border-color` should be  `transparent` or the background color of the parent element.

Comment: Also, while using CSS3 works, keep in mind that this isn't compatible with certain browsers - cough - IE.

Comment: @JKirchartz, setting the opacity to 0 through `rgba` is the same as `transparent`.. although it still shows the same `div`s background and not the element underneath.. (*using the color of the element beneath would work but not if the element below is not a solid color..*)

Comment: @vonkly, very correct, although the OP asks for transitions, so i figured he was aware.. good point though..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli yeah, but you were setting the color to #ff0000 when I posted that comment.

Comment: @JKirchartz, ahh.. makes sense.. i edited it right-away because i hadn't tested it yet..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli that's the only thing I don't like about S.O., little timing foibles like that.

Comment: +1 but, you should always place the standards property below its vendor specific implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that transitions don't work in Opera (11.62) if you just write `border-color`. You have to specify all four borders separately:

```
-o-transition: border-top-color 1s linear, border-right-color 1s linear, border-bottom-color 1s linear, border-left-color 1s linear;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ds5bM/

This is fixed in Opera 12.

Answer (score 0):

just use CSS3 transitions

```
#id_of_element {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```